# How to get relative path from current folder?

Tags: path, cmd

This is what i currently get with FOR loop:

```
FOR /R "ProgramFolder" %%P in (*) do (
echo %%P
)

C:\Folder\Folder2\ProgramFolder\Managed\bolt.dll
C:\Folder\Folder2\ProgramFolder\Resources\fmodstudio.dll
C:\Folder\Folder2\ProgramFolder\Plugins\dll\DynamicWaterNativeWrapper.dll
```

How to get pathes like this?

```
Managed\bolt.dll
Resources\fmodstudio.dll
Plugins\dll\DynamicWaterNativeWrapper.dll
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edited** on dbenham comments

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    pushd c:\somewhere\ProgramFolder
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=\" %%a in (
        'xcopy . "%temp%" /l /s'
    ) do if not "%%b"=="" echo(%%b
    popd
```

The basic idea behind this code is to use the `xcopy` command not to copy, but to retrieve a list (`/l`) of the files that should be processed *with relative paths*. For it to work, it is necessary to first change the current active directory to the required one (`pushd`) and use a relative reference to the current folder (`.`)

The output of `xcopy` command with this configuration will be in the form

```
.\folder\folder\file.ext
```

To remove the prefixing dot and backslash the `for /f` is configured to use the slashes as delimiters and to retrieve the first token (the dot) before the first backslash and the rest of the line as the second token, that is, the relative paths

As the `xcopy` command output includes an aditional line with the total number of files, and this line will result in an aditional blank line in the output of the script, an aditional `if` is included to discard this line.

Comment: +1, Oooh, I had forgotten about this gem of a technique. Instead of PUSHD, you can simply use the root path in place of `.`. You could eliminate output of the blank line with `if "%%b" neq "" echo %%b`

Comment: @dbenham, you are right, corrected the output of the blank line. But sorry, maybe I'm blind now, but I don't understand the `simply use the root path`

Comment: `for /f ... in ('xcopy ProgramFolder "%temp%" /l /s') do ...`. No PUSHD needed

Comment: @dbenham, thank you. The `root` fooled me. While the code in the question references the folder that way, i think the `pushd` is a more general approach, in a different environment the changes should be done out of the loop. But Of course you are right.